# Can't access Nasbox with domain name from within the local network

Tags: networking, router, nas

I have a nasbox at home which i can connect to when im outside of the local network through (nas.example.com) but when i use (nas.example.com) on the local network i get the router control panel instead of the nas box.

Conclusion.
Domain name / port forward works, just not when im on the local network.

I guess my router doesn't recognize the request from within, you guys have any idea?

Router:
Genexis DRGOS
Platform - HRG1000
Product Name - Platinum-6810

Comment: Does it matter, have you not just got a local name you can use?

Comment: It does, i use plugins in my browser. So when i use my laptop i have to change the name/ip every time i come home.

My old router did just fine, so its some kind of setting.